# How to show an empty dropdownlist when another one isn't selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlists both connected to the database, one is called Distritos and the other is called Concelhos, while distritos isn´t selected, concelhos should show empty, when the user selects one of the words of distritos, the Concelhos should show. I want to make it like a state-City relation. 
This is what i have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult getcidades(int? distrito = null)
{
    var concelho =
        Db.Concelhos.OrderBy(r => r.Nome) as IQueryable<Concelho>;

    if (distrito != null)
    {
        concelho = concelho.Where(t => t.Distritos.Id == distrito);                    
    }

    return Json(concelho.Select(r => new { Nome = r.Nome, r.Id }),  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is what i have in my view:

```js
$("#Distrito").on("change", function() {
  var valor = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "@Url.Action("
      getcidades ","
      PiHelper ")",
      data: {
        distrito: valor
      }
    })
    .done(function(concelho) {
      var dropdown = $("#Concelho");

      dropdown.empty().focus();

      console.log(concelho, dropdown)
      for (var i = 0; i < concelho.length; i++) {
        $("<option>")
          .attr("value", concelho[i].Id)
          .text(concelho[i].Nome)
          .appendTo(dropdown);
      }
    })

})
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: when i don´t choose a "Distrito"(it means state) it should show me a blank(empty space in the dropdownlist) "Cidade" (Cidade means City).

Comment: You need to edit you question to explain the issue. If you select the `null` option in the first dropdownlist, then it calls your controller method which returns all `Concelhos` You should be testing for `null` and if so, just empty the 2nd dropdownlist and not call the method. Then change the controller code to `public ActionResult getcidades(int distrito) { var concelho = Db.Concelhos.OrderBy(r => r.Nome)..Where(t => t.Distritos.Id == distrito); return Json(....); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#distritos').each(function() {
    if ($(this).not(':selected')) 
    {
       $('#concelhos').val(0);
    }
});
```

or

```
if ($('#distritos :selected').length == 0)
{
    $('#concelhos options').remove();
}
```